# Error streaming BLOB from Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, streaming, blob

I have some binary data stored in `Blob` in Postgres. I work with the db through JPA but that's not important in this case. I have a spring MVC `@Controller` which should be able to serve this data through an endpoint. And I want to *stream* the data because why to load it all into memory. Roughly like:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
    @Lob  
    Blob data;
}

@RequestMapping(...)
public InputStreamResource getResource(...) {
    return new InputStreamResource(myEntityRepository.findById(id).getData().getBinaryStream());
}
```

This unfortunately gives me:

> java.io.IOException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid
>   large-object descriptor: 1

And I know why: When you work with Blobs you need to [run in transaction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html?is-external=true). Now what I have tried:

1. Annotating the whole controller method `@Transactional` - doesn't help because when Spring starts to copy the stream into the servlet response it is already outside of the transaction aspect. :'(
2. I also validated that if I *inside the controller* copy the input stream into `byte[]` it all works. But this is no streaming.

`byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(myEntityRepository.findById(id).getData().getBinaryStream());
    return new ByteArrayResource(data);`

It is clearly the problem that the aspect doing `@Transactional` is *closer* to the controller method that the one which gets return value and turns it into servlet response.

Is there a way how to *reorder* the aspects? Any other solution?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
It seems it should work simply by doing `@EnableTransactionManagement(order = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` which unfortunately is not the case. Maybe due to `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)` ?

**Edit2:**
This is apparently yet more general problem. The `@RequestMapping` annotated method just returns the `Stream` but only after the invocation completes - including all aspects and `@Transactional` - the returned value (Stream) is processed further. So in fact I will be looking to broaden then *transactional* to the class *which actually calls the controller's method*, possibly the whole `Servlet.doXXX` method. No good news.

Comment: Spring version?

Comment: SPring Boot 1.5

Comment: Is that possible to migrate in `Spring Webflux` which is in spring boot 2.0?

Answer (score -1):

Turned out I overlooked the simplest yet a bit less elegant solution. I can still inject the `HttpServletResponse` or `OutputStream` into the controller's method and copy the Stream inside the controller's method. Not as nice as returning `InputStreamResource` but works.